# Android版Firefox + TampermonkeyでUserScriptを読み込む方法は？

Tags: android, firefox

Android 7.1.1でUserScriptを読み込む方法は？ネット上で嫌な文字列を見る機会が多い為、WebAbornというuserjsをAndroidに導入したいのですがうまくいきません。FirefoxでTampermonkeyのアドオンをインストールし以下のコードを入力したのですがうまくいきませんでした。userjsを読み込めるというTampermonkey(dolphin)というアプリでも同様の結果でした。何がいけないんでしょうか？ファイルパスは`/storage/emulated/0/test/WebAborn.user.js`です。

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name import_webaborn 
// @namespace http://webaborn.herokuapp.com 
// @version 0.1 // @description import local WebAborn.js 
// @author foo 
// @require /storage/emulated/0/test/WebAborn.user.js
// @grant none 
// ==/UserScript==
```

Comment: マルチポスト: https://teratail.com/questions/195046, https://teratail.com/questions/195022

Comment: 質問文に貼られた内容にはコメント文しかなく、肝心のコード部分がありません。配布先からダウンロードした`user.js`をインストールしたのではありませんか？

Comment: マルチポスト　http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1560562562

Comment: マルチポスト　https://okwave.jp/qa/q9625846.html

Comment: 恐らく以下の記事を参考にされたようですが、あくまでPC版のGoogleChromeでの手順なので、 AndroidのFirefoxで使いたいのであれば、まずは配布サイトからダウンロードしたスクリプトを**直接インストール**して試してみるべきかと思います。 - [WebAbornをGoogleChrome version34以降で使う](http://itouhiro.hatenablog.com/entry/20141016/javascript)

Comment: たんたんとマルチポスト先を教えてくださる supa さん htb さんに感謝

Answer (score 1):

StackExchange アプリで画像をアップロードできなかったので代わりに各ステップを詳しく書きます。

1. WebAborn.user.js をダウンロードして開きます。（ダウンロード一覧 about:downloads でファイル名をタップすると、Android に入っているテキストビューワかなんかがそのファイルを開くはずです。）
2. 全部選択してコピーします。
3. Android 版 Firefox に [Tampermoney](https://addons.mozilla.org/ja/android/addon/tampermonkey/) をインストールし、
4. Firefox の右上 ︙ から Tampermonkey を選び Tampermonkey 画面を出し、
5. 新規スクリプト作成を選びます。
6. テキストエリアにすでに一部書かれているのを消して、2でコピーしたものを貼り付けて全て置き換えます。
7. その画面で7行目の

   ```
   // ==/UserScript
   ```

   の行を

   ```
   // ==/UserScript==
   ```

   と修正して ファイル - 保存 を選びます。（WebAborn 自体がきちんとしていないようです。）
8. 該当のキーワードを含んでいそうな web ページを閲覧すると指定の文字で置換されていることが確認できます。

Firefox Nightly (68.0a1) で確認しました。Release 版 (67) でも同じかと思います。

しかしどうも自分の指定したキーワードじゃないところを置換しているような。
[image: 句読点をハートで置き換えるはずがいろんなところを置き換えている]
ま、それは WebAborn 作者にいうなり自分でデバッグするなり、別の話かと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとう御座います3点確認したいことがあります。新規 UserScript 作成画面に WebAborn.user.js の中身を貼り付けて、←これどうやるんですか？修正する箇所がないのですがどこでしょうか？どのように動作してるかスクショ送ってもらえませんか？宜しくお願いします。

Comment: お返事が遅れてすみません。通知してないので気づきませんでした。試してみます。

Comment: firefoxで試したらできました、ありがとう御座います！yandexはchoromeのエクステンションが使えるのですが有効化されませんでした。yandexでも使いたいのですがどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Comment: @brrum よかったです。別のソフトウェアの使い方を知りたいのであれば、この質問からは逸脱するので別の質問を立てるのが良いかと思います。おこなった手順と、その結果どんなメッセージが出たとか状況になったとかを書くのを忘れずに。

Comment: 親切にありがとう御座います。助かりました。特にテキストエディタでファイルを読み込める事を知らなかったので大変勉強になりました。またご縁がありましたら宜しくお願い致します。